# required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This the error iam when I tried start my spring boot application getting on console Action:
Consider defining a bean of type
'java.lang.String' in your
configuration.

My code

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Bean
public void addProduct(String name) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (NULL, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, name);
}
}


@Service
public class ProductService {

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;


public void addProduct(String name) {
    productRepository.addProduct(name);
}
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="product")
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
ProductService productService;

@PostMapping(path="/add/{name}")
public void addProduct(@PathVariable 
String name) {
    productService.addProduct(name);
}
}
```

Comment: remove the @Bean annotation

Answer (score 3):

Here, you are trying to create bean with dependency object of type `String` in `addProduct()`. When Spring application starts, it tries to look for Bean of type `String`. It makes no sense.

So, no need of the `@Bean` annotation. The beans are usually created in classes annotated with `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 1):

try removing @Bean over addproduct method

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, what solved it for me is I created a default constructor so maybe it will help you too.